# In BGL, how to efficiently find an adjacent vertex using a property of a vertex

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I’m having a bidirectional graph (i.e. a directed graph in which it is possible to iterate both the in-edges and the out-edges).

Each vertex, among other internal properties, has a special ID property which is an integer from a finite set (couple of hundreds) which is known at  program's startup, that is – it won’t change during program's life time, but it is unknown at compile time.

This property *is not unique* at the scope of the graph (i.e. there can be two Vertices with the same ID), and therefore cannot be used with named/labeled_graph. *It is however unique in the scope of a given Vertex*, that is both the incoming neighbors and the outgoing neighbors of a vertex should all have different IDs.

My question is whether there is a build in mechanism in BGL to efficiently find an adjacent vertex *u*, of *v* given *u*’s descriptor, the graph, and the ID of *u*.

This can of course be achieve using some external mapping, but it feels like quite a common scenario, and given that the adjacency_list’s first template parameter can be an associative container – it seems only natural to have some kind of find_adjacent(v,g,ID) function, alas, I wasn’t able to find anything like it.

Many thanks,
Andrey

Answer (score 0):

You don't post a sample, but from the description given you could select an ordered set for the `OutEdgeList` and order it by the target vertex ID (which is unique in that scope).

Now you can use `std::lower_bound`/`std::upper_bound`/`std::equal_range` on the out_edges of any given node.

If you prefer you can easily add free functions like `find_adjacent` to hide the implementation.